# Converting the command 'ls | grep x' from linux to DOS

Tags: linux, grep, pipe, dos, ls

Would it be possible / how do you do the Linux command

```
ls | grep x
```

Using Windows DOS?

Comment: Windows has `dir` and `findstr` that are pretty much like `ls` and `grep`. Not sure about DOS. But what you want really achieve? Even `ls | grep x` is not neccessary because it can be done via shell globbing

Comment: I'm not really sure what the point of it is... we were asked to research and i know what it would do on linux but i dont really know how to do it on DOS. I believe 'dir' is the same as 'ls' but how would 'findstr' fit in?

Comment: `findstr` is similiar to `grep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that only way to do that in **DOS** is to use `dir` + `find`. Latter only accepts filename (no pipes allowed), so you will need a termporary file:

```
dir > A:\list.txt
find "CD" A:\list.txt
```

It is also has very limited capabilities comparing with `grep`.

**Windows** has more powerful tool `findstr`:

```
dir | findstr CD
```